# How do I insert a customer purchase history when uploading data?

Tags: data-loader, excel, import

We are a small ecommerce business that works in the B2C model. I am in charge of setting up Salesforce for us and I need to upload all of our customers names, addresses, other information and most importantly purchase history (previous purchases). We have thousands of names with previous online purchases that I need to somehow implement and later be able to work with this information. We currently manage all this information in Excel. How should I set up the field to be able to import all this information - would it be considered a customer field and what kind (how should I set it up) or entered in the description manually? Also, later on, once I have all the information on salesforce, if I need to pull out information about all the customers who have purchased a specific product within the specific period, would I be able to do that? Your help will be greatly appreciated. All details are important for me since I am brand new to Salesforce. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Community! It's about almost setting up the environment. Try to go through some references and raise any issues you are having. Community is ready to give answers to the point. Using the tools like [Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader) you can do most of your stuffs. For the moment **yes** you can analyse your data later on